# Export multiple sheets into multiple PDF - runt-time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I collect several sheets in an array. Those sheets have not always the same name. 
Now I want to export each of these sheets into a PDF, one PDF for each sheet. I found some code here on stack overflow but it ends up with run-time error 13 'type mismatch'.

[Macro to Export Certain Excel Sheets to Separate PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236526/macro-to-export-certain-excel-sheets-to-separate-pdf)

If I select all sheets, in this case from sheet 4 to the last sheet, I manage to export them into one single PDF. So somehow the counting with 'i' is the problem here.

```
    Dim intSheet As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intArray As Integer
    Dim varSheet()
    Dim i As Variant, selectedWS As Variant


    intSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    intArray = -1
    For intCount = 4 To intSheet
        intArray = intArray + 1
        ReDim Preserve varSheet(intArray)
        varSheet(intArray) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(intCount).Name
    Next

selectedWS = Array(varSheet())

For Each i In selectedWS
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\R541254\Projects\" & "test" & i & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Next i
End Sub
```

In the end, each sheet should be exportet in a seperate PDF with the name 'test' and the counted number of 'i'.

Thank you in advance and have a great evening :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an array here:

```
Dim i as Long

For i = 4 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\R541254\Projects\" & "test" & i & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Next i
```